# Binary operation on Graphs

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory

Are there "binary operations" on graphs, which make the set of all graphs,

- a commutative ring or
- a field

For example $G_1 \cdot ( G_2 + G_3) = G_1 \cdot G_2 + G_1 \cdot G_3$

By a graph I mean everything which might be considered a graph, for example a directed graph, undirected graph, graphs with no multiple edges, weighted graphs etc.
If so, is there a reference on how the binary operations are construced?

Comment: Check out en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_product

Comment: Thanks, Do you know of any "algebraic relation" the different type of products fulfill? (for example are two of them associative?) and so on. I managed to find http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571065314000092 but do not have access to it.

Comment: I meant to say distributive instead of associative in my comment above.

Comment: Check out http://www.discuss.wmie.uz.zgora.pl/php/discuss3.php?ip=&url=pdf&nIdA=3544&nIdSesji=-1 This is a 26 page article about many products, See for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If we let $\mathcal{G}_{labeled}:=\{(V,E)\ |\ V\subset \mathbb{N}, E \subset P(V), (\forall S \in E ) (|S| = 2) \}$ (i.e. the set of all labeled graphs) and for any two graphs $G,H$ define $f:V_G\rightarrow V_H$ to be a *mapping of graphs* if $\{u,v\} \in E_G \implies \{f(u),f(v)\} \in E_H$. If we let $[G]_\cong := \{H\ |\ \exists f:H\rightarrow G ,f \text{ is a 1-to-1 &unto mapping of graphs } \}$ we then define the set of graphs as $\mathcal{G}:= \{[G]_\cong \ | \ G \in \mathcal{G}_{labeled}\}$ (i.e. our operations do not care about labels). We define the operation $+:\mathcal{G} \times \mathcal{G} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$, the *sum of graphs*, as follows:

- The easiest way to do this is to define $G+H$ as the graph with vertix set $V_G\coprod V_H$ and with edge set $\{\{u,v\}\ |\ (u,v\in V_G\land \{u,v\} \in E_G )\lor (u,v\in V_H\land \{u,v\} \in E_H\} \cong E_G \coprod E_H  $ where $\coprod $ is the disjoint union of sets.
- We could have alternately defined it as the unique (up to iso.) object $G\coprod H$ that satisfies the following universal property: *for all* graphs $Z$ and graph mappings $f_1:G\rightarrow Z, \ \ f_2:H\rightarrow Z$ 
  $\require{AMScd}$
  \begin{CD}
  Z @>f_2>>H\\
  @VV{f_1}V @VV{id_H}V\\
  G @>{id_G}>> G\coprod H
  \end{CD}
  there *exists a unique* mapping $\varphi :Z \rightarrow G\coprod H $ that makes the proceding diagram commute.

Likewise, we dually define  $\times :\mathcal{G} \times \mathcal{G} \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$, the *product of graphs*, as follows:

- We define $G\times H$ as the graph with vertix set $V_G\prod V_H$ and with edge set $\{(\{u_1,u_2\},\{v_1,v_2\})\ |\ (u_1,u_2\in V_G\land \{u_1,u_2\} \in E_G )\land (v_1,v_2\in V_H\land \{v_1,v_2\} \in E_H\} \cong E_G \prod E_H $ where $\prod $ is the disjoint union of sets.
- We could have alternately defined it as the unique (up to iso.) object $G\coprod H$ that satisfies the following universal property: *for all* graphs $Z$ and graph mappings $f_1:Z\rightarrow G, \ \ f_2:Z\rightarrow G$ 
  $\require{AMScd}$
  \begin{CD}
  G\prod H @>\pi_H>>H\\
  @VV{\pi_G}V @VV{f_2}V\\
  G @>{f_1}>> Z
  \end{CD}
  there *exists a unique* mapping $\vartheta :G\prod H \rightarrow Z $ that makes the proceding diagram commute.

The functions $\varphi, \vartheta$ are usually denoted $f_1\coprod f_2, f_1\prod f_2$ respectively. The proceeding categorical considerations show that these two operations are the most natural defintions of sum and product with which you can equip the caetgory of graphs. It is straightforward to see that $+,\times $ satisfy the defintions of associatvity, commutativity, and distributivity and furthermore notice that if we define $\mathbf{0} := (\emptyset ,\emptyset)$ and $\mathbf{1} := (\{1\},\emptyset)$ then notice that

- $\forall G(\mathbf{0} + G \cong G + \mathbf{0} \cong G)$
- $\forall G(\mathbf{1} \times G \cong G 
  \times \mathbf{1} \cong G)$

Therefore $(\mathcal{G},+,\times,\mathbf{0},\mathbf{1})$ have the desired commutative ring. Here is a potential research problem: **Is there a finite set of generators for this ring?** Whereby I mean is there a fintie set $S \subset \mathcal{G}$ such that the following recursively defined set:

- $S \subset X_S$
- $G,H \in X_S \implies G+H \in X_S$
- $G,H \in X_S \implies G\times H \in X_S$

satisfies $X_S =\mathcal{G}$.